# Change keyboard repeat rate through powershell

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I have an issue with my laptop wherein the repeat rate for the keyboard gets really slow after waking up from hibernation. I can fix this by adjusting the rate down in the control panel, applying the new rate, and then adjusting it up again and applying. But I'd rather not do that every time.

I found where the repeat rate is stored in the registry "HKCU:\Control Panel\Keyboard\KeyboardSpeed" and can set it via powershell. However, the new rate doesn't seem to be applied (i.e. the repeat rate is unaffected regardless of what I set the value to). There must be something else that I need to do to get the rate to stick, but I don't know what that is. For the record, here's how I'm setting the registry value:

```
set-itemproperty "HKCU:\Control Panel\Keyboard\" -name KeyboardSpeed -Value 3
```

Comment: [Answer over here](http://superuser.com/questions/605880/how-to-reduce-keyboard-speed-in-windows-xp-and-7)

Comment: If you're referring to the `rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters` bit, that doesn't seem to work for me. That is, I can update the registry value and run that command and the keyboard repeat rate is unaffected.

Comment: [See if this utility helps](https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=41881.0)

Comment: I have the same issue here. Did you ever find a solution? For now, I press the Windows key, start to type "Keyboard" (in my language), and in that dialog press Enter to apply the already set values. (Win11 here but should be the same in earlier versions.)

Comment: Same here... "mode con delay=0 >nul 2>nul" in a batch file that's executed everytime I log in helps most of the time. Not always :(

Answer (score 2):

After some web research and tinkering, I made this:

https://gist.github.com/ygoe/4c03a9a2b9485356eb56513068607001

It's actually C# code but packaged in PowerShell/CMD. Experienced PowerShell coders could probably also do this with plain PS code.

The code uses the native [`SystemParametersInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa) function with the actions `SPI_SETKEYBOARDDELAY` and `SPI_SETKEYBOARDSPEED` to alter the keyboard settings. It is applied immediately and also reflected in the according Windows configuration dialog.